# minimum_number_should_match with nested must bool

Tags: elasticsearch

I have some documents in elasticsearch that have a list of key-value pairs. Here are some examples.

```
document 1:
{
    data: [
        {
            key: key1,
            value: value1
        },
        {
            key: key1,
            value: value2
        },
    ]
}

document 2:
{
    data: [
        {
            key: key2,
            value: blah
        },
        {
            key: key1,
            value: value2
        },
    ]
}

document 3:
{
    data: [
        {
            key: key1,
            value: value3
        },
        {
            key: key1,
            value: value2
        },
        {
            key: key1,
            value: somevalue
        }
    ]
}

document 4:
{
    data: [
        {
            key: key3,
            value: blah
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I want all document that have **at least 2** of the values `[value1, value2, value3]` with key `key1`.
So from the example, I need documents **1 and 3** but **not 2 or 4**.

So far my query looks like this:

```
"query": {
    "nested": {
        "path": "data",
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "should": [
                    {
                        "bool": {
                            "must": [
                                {
                                    "term": {
                                        "key": key1
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "term": {
                                        "value": {
                                            "value": "value1",
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "bool": {
                            "must": [
                                {
                                    "term": {
                                        "key": key1
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "term": {
                                        "value": {
                                            "value": "value2",
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "bool": {
                            "must": [
                                {
                                    "term": {
                                        "key": key1
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "term": {
                                        "value": {
                                            "value": "value3",
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "minimum_number_should_match": 2
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But it doesn't return any matches at all. 
From what I understand, `minimum_number_should_match` just ensures that a document will only be returned if it matches at least the given minimum `should` occurences in the `bool query`.

- [Minimum Should Match Documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-minimum-should-match.html)
- [Bool Query Documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-minimum-should-match.html)

But it seems like I don't fully understand how it works.
How exactly do I get `minimum_number_should_match` to work with a nested bool query, or is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the nested query goes into each `data` object and looks at a single *key, value* pair. 
Thus it's impossible for it to match on more than one value (each *key, value* pair only has one value).

I had to split each value match into it's own nested query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "data",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "key": "key1"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "value": {
                        "value": "value1"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "data",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "key": "key1"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "value": {
                        "value": "value2"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "data",
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {
                  "term": {
                    "key": "key1"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "term": {
                    "value": {
                      "value": "value3"
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 2
    }
  }
}
```

This means the query can match on multiple of the `data` fields, and if 2 of the should queries match, then the document matches the entire query.

Answer (score 0):

This query should work for you. The only place where I doubt it will go wrong is to use keyword "value" as a field. You can try that. Here is the query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "data",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "key": {
                  "value": "key1"
                }
              }
            }
          ],"should": [
            {
              "term": {
                "value": {
                  "value": "value1"
                }
              }
            },{
              "term": {
                "value": {
                  "value": "value2"
                }
              }
            },{
              "term": {
                "value": {
                  "value": "value3"
                }
              }
            },{
              "term": {
                "value": {
                  "value": "value4"
                }
              }
            }
          ],"minimum_number_should_match": 2
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As to how minimum_number_should_match works, you are right. It tries to match the minimum possible queries which come under "should" part of bool query.

Comment: I don't actually have the word 'value' as a field. This is just an example to show the structure of my documents. I think it could have something to do with `minimum_number_should_match`  working differently for nested bools?